# Add some custom button in data table editor lightbox

Tags: jquery, datatables

Please help me

How to add some more addition button in datatable editor lightbox

Like save I want to add cancel button in editor lightbox

Comment: Please inshift function of the editor TableTools.BUTTONS.editor_create.formButtons.unshift

Comment: @kuldeepraj thanks for fast reply I will do by this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add by this code

```
TableTools.BUTTONS.editor_create.formButtons.unshift(
{
"label": "Cancel",
"className":"btn btn-link",
"fn": function () {
this.close();
}
});
```